# Writing a function that converts 0's to 1's and vice versa. Program works or doesn't work depending on whether I use += or ==

Tags: python, string, for-loop, binary

```
def flip_b(binary):
    b_string = ""
    for i in range(len(binary)):
        if binary[i] == '1':
            b_string += '0' # If I set the += to == the function doesn't work
        else:
            b_string += '1'
    return b_string
```

What's the difference between += and == here?

Comment: == is not an assignment.

Answer (score 1):

`==` is for comparison

```py
>>> 5 == 4
False
>>> 4 == 4
True
```

`+=` is shorthand for `x = x + y`, so

```py
>>> x = 5
5
>>> x = x + 5
10
>>> x = 5
5
>>> x += 5
10
```

Comment: I think it would be more helpful if you showed concatenation rather than addition, to match what's in the code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

The += operator is just a tricky sum between two values, or in this case a concatenation of strings.

b_string += "0" is the same as b_string = b_string + "0".

The == operator is a totally different and unrelated thing: it is used to check if two values are equal. It always produces a True or False value.

In your case, your code starts by creating an empty string, then iterates through a list with a for loop, for every element in the list checks if it is "1" or "0" (hence the == operator) and adds to the empty string the opposite character (hence the += operator). After iterating through the whole list, you get an entire string with flipped 1s and 0s.